# Suggest Edit in Android app when queue is full

Tags: feature-request, edits, android-app, user-experience

When the Suggested edit queue is full and I try to suggest an edit over the web site, the `edit` link is disabled and shows a tooltip at hover, indicating that I'm unable to suggest an edit:

[image: Edit queue full on website]

However, using the Android app, there is nothing indicating that the edit queue is full:

[image: Edit queue full in Android app]

Just after I wrote my edit and try to suggest it, this red banner appears, and I must discard my draft:

[image: Full edit queue - red banner in Android app]]

...Which results in big frustration, because improving a question on a smartphone is not as easy as on a computer and - sometimes - takes time.

**It would be a great improvement if the `suggest edit` button would be disabled until previous edits are reviewed, just like on the web page, wouldn't it?**

Comment: Well the desktop version of this page already has that feature. I wonder the queue got full while you edited the question.

Comment: No, I made this screenshot by clicking on _suggest edit_ on a question which queue was already full, (compared betw. App and Desktop)

Comment: This is the first time I hear about a suggestion queue, can someone please explain what is it exactly?

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284) should esplain it.